# for loop not accessing all of the elements in a list python

Tags: python

The class below is driving me crazy.  It is stuck on the for loop.  I'm unsure why it will not access the last element in self.job_ids.  This should be working.  Any ideas why this for loop does not work inside the class but it works perfectly find outside the class?

import subprocess

```
class job_runner():

    def __init__(self, user_id='staffner'):
        self.job_ids = ['12054807', '12054808', '12054809', '12054810', '12054811', '12054812', '12054813', '10', '100']

        self.user_id = user_id

    def update_running_jobs(self):
        '''
            () ->
            Remove job ids from self.job_ids which  completed
        '''
        # find currently running jobs
        curr_running = self.find_running_jobs()

        #iterate over self.job_ids and see if they are in the currently running jobs
        working_ids = self.job_ids
        print 'start working ids:'
        print working_ids
        for j_id in working_ids:

            # for some reason I can not access the last id in the list
            print j_id

            if j_id not in curr_running:
                self.job_ids.remove(j_id)
        print 'job_ids'
        print self.job_ids

    def find_running_jobs(self):
        '''
            () -> list running ids

            Find what job ids are still running on the high performance cluster
        '''
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['squeue -u %s --Format=arrayjobid'%(self.user_id)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        out, err = proc.communicate()

        if err == None:

            out_list = out.replace('ARRAY_JOB_ID', '').replace(' ', '').split('\n')

            # filter out any empty strings
            out_list = filter(None, out_list)
            return out_list

        else:
            return False

curr_jobs = job_runner()

curr_jobs.update_running_jobs()
```

Here's the output (as you can see 100 is never accessed):

```
start working ids:
['12054807', '12054808', '12054809', '12054810', '12054811', '12054812', '12054813', '10', '100']
12054807
12054808
12054809
12054810
12054811
12054812
12054813
10
job_ids
['12054807', '12054808', '12054809', '12054810', '12054811', '12054812', '12054813', '100']
```

Comment: It works fine on my machine

Comment: Is there any reason why it wouldn't work on one machine but works on another?

Comment: If I remove `find_running_jobs()` call and also it's related loop from the code it shows all the items, but running your complete code, my machine print `100` but doesnt print `10` !!!

Comment: Because you are modifying the container while iterating over it. You set `       working_ids = self.job_ids` But then in the loop you `self.job_ids.remove(j_id)`

Comment: The issue here is [a shallow vs. deep copy of the list](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php). Modifying `working_ids` is also modifying original list, so you are changing same list you are iterating over as they point to the same object.

Comment: @Dan no, the issue is there is neither a deep nor shallow *copy at all*. A shallow copy would be just fine, actually.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for clarifying, that's what I meant. This is assignment rather than copy (I meant a copy of the pointer, but that concept does not really apply in Python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change:

```
working_ids = self.job_ids
```

to:

```
working_ids = self.job_ids[:]  # create a copy of job_ids and use it
```

Explanation: you're modifying the list while iterating it which causes unexpected results, changing the code you'll iterate a *copy* of the list.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I thought I was making a copy.

Comment: @Samantha just remember that *assignment never, ever copies* in Python.

Comment: "... never ever copies _data_" - it copies a reference to the object